# How would you store this data

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, save, load

I have a game and I need to store this data:

- Country
- City
- Level

There are 5 countries, 5 cities per country, and x levels per city.

What would be the best way to store this data, i'm looking to store the level details, such as completed, time taken, etc

Then i'm looking to access the level data by Leveldata[countryindex, cityindex].

I thought of multidimensional lists, or dictionaries, but wondered what you guys think is best practice?

I'd also need to save this data in JSON.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A structure of classes mentioned by Kirill Polishchuk, marked as Serializable, but with some array operator overloads will do what you need.

Then you can use Unity's built-in JsonUtility to serialise to json and write to the disk (or PlayerPrefs as a string). In the following code, I add a Save and Load method to the LevelData class that does this for you.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Level
{
    public int Score;
    // ...
}

[System.Serializable]
public class City
{
    public List<Level> Levels = new List<Level>();
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Country
{
    public List<City> Cities = new List<City>();

    public City this[int cityIndex]
    {
        get
        {
            if (cityIndex < 0 || cityIndex >= Cities.Count)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                return Cities[cityIndex];
            }
        }
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class LevelData
{
    public List<Country> Countries = new List<Country>();

    public List<Level> this[int countryIndex, int cityIndex]
    {
        get
        {
            if (countryIndex < 0 || countryIndex >= Countries.Count)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                City city = Countries[countryIndex][cityIndex];
                if (city != null)
                {
                    return city.Levels;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public void Save(string path)
    {
        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(this);

        // Note: add IO exception handling here!
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, json);
    }

    public static LevelData Load(string path)
    {
        // Note: add check that the path exists, and also a try/catch for parse errors
        LevelData data = JsonUtility.FromJson<LevelData>(path);

        if (data != null)
        {
            return data;
        }
        else
        {
            return new LevelData();
        }
    }
```

You may need to add setters for creating the country and city objects. Or, if you add LevelData as a public variable to a script, this structure will be visible in the Unity editor.

And to add and save level:

```
LevelData data = LevelData.Load(path);
// Here I assume your countries and cities already exist in the structure
List<Level> levels = data[1,2];
// todo: check that levels is not null! 

Level l = new Level();  
// add all info to l
levels.Add(l);

data.Save(path);
```

Comment: So on a level completion, how would I go about adding that to the data structure?

Comment: Seeing as the `[,]` operator of LevelData returns the reference to a `List<Level>`, all you need to do is call `Add` on this list to add your new level. I've updated the answer to show this.

Comment: So, to populate the level list for the first time, i tried:

Comment: LevelData data;
    public List<Level> levels;

if (_FirstPlay == 0)
        {
            _FirstPlay = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < _CountrySize; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < _MonumentSize; ++j)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < _LevelSize[i, j]; ++k)
                    {
                        Level l = new Level();
                        // add all info to l
                        levels.Add(l);
                    }
                }
            }

          // save
        }
        else
// load

Comment: but how would i do the loading and saving of the level list?

Answer (score 0):

Create a proper data-model, e.g.:

```
public class Level
{
    public TimeSpan TimeTaken { get; set; }
    // level specific data
}

public class City
{
    public IList<Level> Levels { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public IList<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can simply use [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to serialize/deserialize to/from JSON, e.g.:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(country);
```

Comment: Then i'm looking to access the level data by Leveldata[countryindex, cityindex], this has everything separate?

Comment: Add a custom indexer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/

Comment: The whole thing could be wrapped into a Data class that contains a list of countries. At each level (Data, Country, City), you have a dictionary string, object to retrieve the content fast and easy. Then at Data level you can have a method that takes the two parameters and first get the country, then gets the city from that country and returns a list of levels. That method would also perform the necessary checks to make sure the parameters are right.